# One hour too much in date formatting using date(1)

Tags: linux, macos, bash, date-format

If I execute the following commands in the terminal

```
start=$(date +%s)
# wait a few seconds …
end=$(date +%s)

time=$(dc <<< "$end $start -p")
echo "$time"

echo "$(date -jr $time +%H:%M:%S)"
```

I get the weird output

```
10       # This is ok, I executed the second line ten seconds after the first one
01:00:10 # But here *** where does the one hour come from?
```

Can anyone explain, where the one our comes from (I'm using Mac OS 10.8)?
And, if there's no way to suppress this, how to change the output or achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date -jr takes a unix timestamp (number of seconds since midnight jan 1 1970 GMT) and converts it to the equivalent local time. I'm betting you're running in a timezone that is one hour ahead of GMT. Ten seconds after midnight jan 1 1970 in GMT is one hour and ten seconds after midnight jan 1 1970 in CET, for example.

If you use the "-u" switch, you'll get UTC time. So this might work for you:

```
date -jur 10 '+%H:%M:%S'
```